# Handle when CloudTable.ExecuteAsync times out

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I have the following code:

```
var operation = TableOperation.InsertOrReplace(entity);                
var options = new TableRequestOptions { MaximumExecutionTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10) };
var context = new OperationContext();
var result = await table.ExecuteAsync(operation, options, context);
```

As you can see, I have set it to give up after 10 seconds.

When it hits the limit, the fourth line above apparently throws a **NullReferenceException**.

I would not like to catch that exception.

What would be the best way to handle this?

Maybe instead of await I can check the Task?

Or maybe there is something on the OperationContext?

Update with StackTrace - not a lot to go on.

```
System.NullReferenceException:
   at Save.Save+<SaveEntity>d__3.MoveNext (Save, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=nullSave, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: E:\Code\Save\Save.csSave, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: 164)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Save.Save+<Run>d__2.MoveNext (Save, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=nullSave, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: E:\Code\Save\Save.csSave, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: 92)
```

Comment: Not really understanding what exactly you would like to do. Can you elaborate more please?

Comment: Yes. I would like to catch whenever the timeout has been reached and return a more controlled response to the caller. Some times it throws StorageException with certain status codes but some times it throws NullReferenceException instead. I have read this might happen as part of await if the method unexpectedly return null so maybe that is what is happening.

Comment: Hmmm....When you get `NullReferenceException`, does it tell you for what variable it is getting it? Ideally you should get `StorageException` back all the time. If possible, share the stack trace as well.

Comment: I have added the StackTrace

Comment: It looks like you wrote your own class to save an entity that’s not behaving properly. You may want to add code for that as well.